# Are boost::graph algorithms capable of using previous solution to solve closely related newer problems faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

I have a max flow problem defined on the following graph:

[image: Max flow problem]

Initially, capacity on all four edges is 4 units each. I seek the maximum flow value from 0 to 3. The answer is 8. (4 units along path 0->1->3 and 4 units along path 0->2->3)

The following code creates the graph and finds the max flow.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/edmonds_karp_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list_traits<vecS, vecS, directedS> Traits;

typedef adjacency_list<
    vecS, vecS, directedS,

    property<
    vertex_name_t, std::string,
    property<vertex_index_t, int,
    property<vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type,
    property<vertex_distance_t, double,
    property<vertex_predecessor_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>
    > > > >,

    property<
    edge_index_t, int,
    property<edge_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_weight_t, double,
    property<edge_residual_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>
> > > > >
Graph;

int main() {
    Graph g;
    property_map<Graph, edge_index_t>::type             e = get(edge_index, g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_capacity_t>::type          cap = get(edge_capacity, g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_weight_t>::type            cost   = get(edge_weight,            g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_residual_capacity_t>::type rescap = get(edge_residual_capacity, g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_reverse_t>::type           rev = get(edge_reverse, g);

    int nonodes = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < nonodes; i++) {
        Traits::vertex_descriptor vd;
        vd = add_vertex(g);
        assert(vd == i);
    }

    // Create edges
    Traits::edge_descriptor edf, edb; // Max flow algorithms seem to want both forward and backward edges. edf is for
                                      // forward, edb is for backward


    edf = (add_edge(0, 1, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(1, 0, g)).first;

    e[edf] = 0;
    e[edb] = 1;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    edf = (add_edge(0, 2, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(2, 0, g)).first;
    e[edf] = 2;
    e[edb] = 3;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    edf = (add_edge(1, 3, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(3, 1, g)).first;
    e[edf] = 4;
    e[edb] = 5;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    edf = (add_edge(2, 3, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(3, 2, g)).first;
    e[edf] = 6;
    e[edb] = 7;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    double flow = boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, 0, 3);
    std::cout << "Flow: " << flow << "\n";
}
```

Now, suppose I change the problem *slightly* such that the capacity of edges (1,3) and (2,3) are 5 each instead of 4 each, and re-solve the max flow problem, does `boost::graph` solve this modified problem from scratch, as if it were a completely new problem? Or, does it use the solution of the previous problem intelligently so that the new problem can be solved immediately by inspection?

What I mean by inspection here, is that the new problem has the optimal solution of 8 units still, since the minimum cut is {0} and {1,2,3} which has capacity 8. Since the minimum cut capacity has not changed by the change of edge capacities of (1,3) and (2,3) to 5, the solution to the new problem is still 8. [Reference to max-flow min-cut theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)

> Edited to add: In linear programming theoretical terms, this would
>   mean that the current basis is still optimal. Or, atleast, it is near optimal. That is, within a few additional iterations the optimal solution can be found obviating the need for having to solve the problem from scratch. Another example would be
>   in a shortest path algorithm, if the cost of an arc/edge that is not
>   on the optimal route from source to destination is increased, then the
>   shortest path problem need not be re-solved - the previous solution
>   continues to be optimal.

I used the below code to check the changed solution. It is still 8, but is there a way to figure out whether `boost::graph` has solved this by inspection or whether it has solved this problem from scratch?

Obviously, solving the problem by inspection will be faster than solving the problem from scratch.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/edmonds_karp_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list_traits<vecS, vecS, directedS> Traits;

typedef adjacency_list<
    vecS, vecS, directedS,

    property<
    vertex_name_t, std::string,
    property<vertex_index_t, int,
    property<vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type,
    property<vertex_distance_t, double,
    property<vertex_predecessor_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>
    > > > >,

    property<
    edge_index_t, int,
    property<edge_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_weight_t, double,
    property<edge_residual_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>
> > > > >
Graph;

int main() {
    Graph g;
    property_map<Graph, edge_index_t>::type             e = get(edge_index, g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_capacity_t>::type          cap = get(edge_capacity, g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_weight_t>::type            cost   = get(edge_weight,            g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_residual_capacity_t>::type rescap = get(edge_residual_capacity, g);
    property_map<Graph, edge_reverse_t>::type           rev = get(edge_reverse, g);

    int nonodes = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < nonodes; i++) {
        Traits::vertex_descriptor vd;
        vd = add_vertex(g);
        assert(vd == i);
    }

    // Create edges
    Traits::edge_descriptor edf, edb; // Max flow algorithms seem to want both forward and backward edges. edf is for
                                      // forward, edb is for backward


    edf = (add_edge(0, 1, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(1, 0, g)).first;

    e[edf] = 0;
    e[edb] = 1;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    edf = (add_edge(0, 2, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(2, 0, g)).first;
    e[edf] = 2;
    e[edb] = 3;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    edf = (add_edge(1, 3, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(3, 1, g)).first;
    e[edf] = 4;
    e[edb] = 5;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    edf = (add_edge(2, 3, g)).first;
    edb = (add_edge(3, 2, g)).first;
    e[edf] = 6;
    e[edb] = 7;
    cap[edf] = 4;
    cap[edb] = 4;
    rev[edf] = edb;
    rev[edb] = edf;

    double flow = boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, 0, 3);
    std::cout << "Flow: " << flow << "\n";
    std::cout << "c flow values:" << std::endl;

//Now trying to change the capacities of certain edges to figure out if boost redoes the problem or intelligently modifies previous solution...
    graph_traits < Graph >::out_edge_iterator ei, e_end;
    for (tie(ei, e_end) = out_edges(1, g); ei != e_end; ++ei)
        if (target(*ei, g) == 3)
            cap[*ei] = 5;//Change capacity of forward arc (1,3) to 5
    for (tie(ei, e_end) = out_edges(2, g); ei != e_end; ++ei)
        if (target(*ei, g) == 3)
            cap[*ei] = 5;//Change capacity of forward arc (2,3) to 5
    for (tie(ei, e_end) = out_edges(3, g); ei != e_end; ++ei)
        if (target(*ei, g) == 1 || target(*ei, g) == 2)
            cap[*ei] = 5;//Change capacity of backward arcs (3,1)  and (3,2) to 5
    flow = boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, 0, 3);
    std::cout << "Flow: " << flow << "\n";
}
```

Closely related to the above question is: Is there a way (an `int` returning method() ) to figure out how much *work* has gone into solving each call to `boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, 0, 3)` above? Note that there are two places in the immediately preceding code where this algorithm is called. By work, I mean integer number of iterations from start until the problem is solved?

Comment: Some algorithms are. E.g. there's a version of connected_components that uses disjoint-set state to incrementally find components of a growing graph: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph/doc/incremental_components.html

Comment: @sehe thanks, but that was not what I was referring to. I was more interested in classical graph algorithms, such as shortest path, or min cost flow, max flow or minimum spanning tree, etc. From what I gather thus far, the graph library does not use the previous solution. Do you know if there is a way to "feed in" a partial solution so that these algorithms start from an advanced state rather than from scratch? For instance, if I am solving 1000 Dijkstra's shortest path problems, each differing from the previous in the cost of exactly 1 arc, solving each problem from scratch will be expensive!

Comment: I mentioned what I do know. That was in response to the question title. Of course I noticed the question text shifts the topic towards max-flow algos, otherwise I'd have _answered_ instead of commented. In general I find no (other) reference to incremental algorithms in BGL. There's quite some research about it, so there might be other libraries that do. Depending on your particular domain problem it might be easy to update your own incremental graph properties on modification.

Comment: My logic is: It's a lot of extra effort to implement algorithms that can benefit from solutions to similar problems (in the limit you get dynamic algorithms, which are significantly more complicated even for "simple" problems like MST).  So *if they had* gone to the effort of implementing these more difficult, complex algorithms, they would have certainly announced the availability of these features in the docs.