# Query on Graph implementation for Route suggestion

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have a set of dynamic data, say journey time or flight duration and I need to build something like a google map that gives suggestions on alternative routes, where do I start ? I am specifically looking for pointers on the below questions.

1. I think we need to use some sort of Graph. If so, How do I start building the graph? Shall I start populating the graph continuously as and when the data comes in or is there any best practice involved?

2.) Are the graphs pre drawn and the vertices searched when user searched for source and destination or are the graphs constructed during user search?

3.) What happens when there is an route update - say a no-entry road or such. Will the graphs need to be redrawn or are they usually updated?

Any other data on how to start with this and examples in java will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, this is too ambitious a project to be answered fully on SO. Yet, the following may be useful pointers to consider:

1. Graph algorithms are special cases of general linear/integer
   programs. Such problems are properly solved either by a general purpose solver such as [CPLEX](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/), or by more specialized algorithms developed specifically for the problem instance on hand.
2. Transportation designers and wireless routing electrical engineers deal with such problems routinely. [One example based on a simple google scholar search for dynamic routing.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/48894/?reload=true) GPS software also has such algorithms built-in.
3. Designing a shortest path algorithm is not difficult. However, as stated, your problem requires repeated solutions to slightly differing problems. So, it is likely that your performance will take a hit if these problems are solved from scratch. Linear programming/integer programming *solvers* (such as CPLEX) in many cases are intelligent enough to try to use previous solutions in order to try to solve closely related yet different problems much quicker. See the following thread, for instance: [Are boost::graph algorithms capable of using previous solution to solve closely related newer problems faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986312/are-boostgraph-algorithms-capable-of-using-previous-solution-to-solve-closely)
4. I used to/still write code for network flow problems myself since many of the algorithms I need to design are rather specialized. But, you may benefit from using pre-built libraries in C++ (not sure about Java) such as `boost::graph`.